# You can not install Windows 8.1 on ubuntu 15.04 phenon IIx6 1090T

Tags: system-installation, windows-8

Download ubuntu, then download yumi and create a multiboot USB, set the priority of the bios, but every time I reboot does not start installing Linux, I do not know what could be wrong? or am I doing wrong? but I can not install the operating system with Windows 8.1

features

ASUS PC motherboard Hibrit CFX CPU phenon IIX6 1090T,
video Gigabyte GT 240 1Gb,
4 GB of RAM

It is the first time I install ubuntu, as I fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Comment: It is the first time I install ubuntu, as I fix it?

Comment: Did you read manuals? Did it help. Try to write boot flash with something else.

Comment: No idea what you're talking about

Comment: I gave a link in first comment. There are answers about how to install Ubuntu with Win 8. Did you try that?

Comment: clickeo where I am new at this

Comment: FIRST COMMENT. JUST CLICK THE LINK.

Answer (score -2):

You can use Unetbootin to make bootable Linux USB stick.

```
sudo apt-get install unetbootin
```

Here is the version for Windows: http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

Comment: They will need a working Ubuntu installation to do that.

Comment: No. It can be downloaded from Sourceforge for Windows. http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

Comment: `sudo apt-get install` will not download anything from Sourceforge. Perhaps you could [edit] your answer with a link to the appropriate Sourceforge page and some instructions for the OP to follow.

Comment: UNetbootin doesn't work on Windows 8 and it even says so on the same webpage you linked to in your answer.

Comment: Well then I do with this problem, install or as I start?

Comment: @karel Unetbooting working on Windows 8.1 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PVIDYQ3YAfo

Comment: @UncleLeo My troll scepticism kicked in when I watched the video you linked to. Why is it narrated by a computer generated voice instead of a human voice? Why does the official Ubuntu website recommend Universal USB Installer (which officially supports Windows 8) over UNetbootin (which is also an app in the Ubuntu Software Center? And finally why doesn't UNetbooptin itself say that it supports Windows 8?

Comment: Well I think I am explaining badly believe, and I have Windows 8.1 installed and want to put Ubuntu 15.04 and I will not start and perform the initial settings

Comment: That's what I was waiting for, the firsthand experience of a user of UNetbootin on Windows 8. If you tried UNetbootin on Windows 8 and it actually worked I would like to know that.

Comment: @karel if you dont believe me u can try it yourself

Comment: the translation into English is something bad

Comment: I just want to know if you tried itself and did it work for you?

Comment: but I still can not install it like I do? I can not find solution

Comment: @karel i said this 2 comments before

Comment: @UncleLeo Thanks for providing the information. A lot of UNetbootin users who got spooked by the official UNetbootin systems requirements would be happy to know that.

Comment: @karel You are welcome! Thanks for -1 to my correct answer

Comment: It is for myself, and I use it as soon as possible but did not know that the installation was so complicated, well compared to Unetbootin not start the installation is not my fault that this happens, this is my first time that I want to install ubuntu, I hope not be doing or causing discomfort, I just want to solve my problem, thanks in advance

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer. Why would I downvote it? I just wanted to ask about UNetbootin on Windows 8 from someone who had actually tried it.  I'm getting information from you, so if anything I would upvote it, not downvote it.

Comment: By the way @karel. Your know that Windows 8.1 support Win32 runtime apps which one is Unetbootin?

Comment: Yes, I already knew about compatibility mode, but every time I tried to ask someone about it they told me... oh well, I haven't tried it myself, so try it yourself if you're that interested in it and then you tell me if it works or not. Why should I do that? The official Ubuntu website already says to use Universal USB Installer with Windows. You're the first person who actually told me that he tried UNetbootin in Windows 8 and it worked. This has been going on for so long that I could write a short story about it and send it to *Fantasy and Science Fiction*. –

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24528/discussion-on-answer-by-uncle-leo-you-can-not-install-windows-8-1-on-ubuntu-15-0).